# Logback Configuration from Config Server optionally

Tags: spring-cloud, logback

I develop an Application with Spring Boot based on a micro-service architecture and use the config-server from Spring cloud.
[link to documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/)

I have Service A, which makes a call to this config-server in order to get the configuration for the logging system logback in the bootstrap-phase of the spring application.
This works fine when the config-server is online and reachable.
In case of a connection issue to the server i want to ensure, that each service has a configuration file, so i also have a local configuration as fallback in under the resources folder. (maybe not up2date, but better then nothing).
In bootstrap.yml file of Service A i have these lines:

```xml
spring:
  application:
    name: service-discovery
  config: 
    import: optional:configserver:http://${server.config.url}
logging:
  config: http://${server.config.url}/config/spring/main/logging/logback.xml
```

**logging.config** fetches the xml-configuration file from the config-server, but when the server is offline, the app crashes.

Is there a possability to make this call optionally or at least to not crash the app?

Thanks in previous!

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud config server will also be used for other configurations for your application, how would your application run if the config server is not running? Whole application will be failed to start if the config server is not working. Please check.

Another option to keep config server running is to use multiple config servers and give the url of config server comma separated in your applications bootstrap.properties

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).